# Rails 7 controller decorator uninitialised constant error in production only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, decorator, rails-engines, ruby-on-rails-7

I am getting the following error `zeitwerk/loader/helpers.rb:95:in const_get': uninitialized constant Controllers::BasePublicDecorator (NameError)`
This is an error in a local production console using `rails c -e production` but not an issue in development which works perfectly.

In an engine, `CcsCms::PublicTheme`, I have a decorator I am using to extend the controller of another `CcsCms::Core` engine and it is this decorator that is causing the error.

> public_theme/app/decorators/decorators/controllers/base_public_decorator.rb

```
CcsCms::BasePublicController.class_eval do
  before_action :set_theme #ensure that @current_theme is available for the
                          #header in all public views

  private

    def set_theme
      @current_theme = CcsCms::PublicTheme::Theme.current_theme
    end
end
```

This functionality is working perfectly in development but fails in production with an error as follows

The controller I am trying to decorate in the CcsCms::Core engine is CcsCms::BasePublicController.rb

```
module CcsCms
  class BasePublicController < ApplicationController
    layout "ccs_cms/layouts/public"

    protected
      def authorize
      end
  end
end
```

in the theme engine with the decorator I am trying to use I have a Gemfile that defines the core engine as follows

```
gem 'ccs_cms_core', path: '../core'
```

In the ccs_cms_public_theme.gemspec I am requiring the core engine as a dependency

```
  spec.add_dependency "ccs_cms_core"
```

in the engine.rb I am requiring the core engine and loading the decorator paths in a `config.to_prepare do` block

```
require "deface"
require 'ccs_cms_admin_dashboard'
require 'ccs_cms_custom_page'
require 'ccs_cms_core'
require 'css_menu'
#require 'tinymce-rails'
require 'delayed_job_active_record'
require 'daemons'
require 'sprockets/railtie'
require 'sassc-rails'

module CcsCms
  module PublicTheme
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace CcsCms::PublicTheme
      paths["app/views"] << "app/views/ccs_cms/public_theme"

      initializer "ccs_cms.assets.precompile" do |app|
        app.config.assets.precompile += %w( public_theme_manifest.js )
      end

      initializer :assets do |config|
        Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("")
      end

      initializer :append_migrations do |app|
        unless app.root.to_s.match?(root.to_s)
          config.paths['db/migrate'].expanded.each do |p|
            app.config.paths['db/migrate'] << p
          end
        end
      end

      initializer :active_job_setup do |app|
        app.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
      end

      config.to_prepare do
        Dir.glob(Engine.root.join("app", "decorators", "**", "*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
          Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
        end
      end

      config.generators do |g|
        g.test_framework :rspec,
          fixtures: false,
          request: false,
          view_specs: false,
          helper_specs: false,
          controller_specs: false,
          routing_specs: false
        g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot
        g.factory_bot dir: 'spec/factories'
      end

    end
  end
end
```

Given that my decorator is given the same name as the controller it is decorating from the core engine but with the .decorator extension I am pretty certain that is everything hooked up correctly, as mentioned, this works perfectly in development but I am unable to start a rails console in a production environment due to this error.
It seems that the class_eval is failing somehow and I can only think that this may be a path issue but I can not figure it out

**UPDATE**
After quite a big learning curve, thank's muchly to @debugger comments and @Xavier Noria
answer it is clear that my issue comes down to Zeitworks autoload functionality

Rails guides [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-once-paths)  has an interesting and appealing solution to me

> Another use case are engines decorating framework classes:

```
initializer "decorate ActionController::Base" do  
> ActiveSupport.on_load(:action_controller_base) do
>     include MyDecoration   end end
```

> There, the module object stored in MyDecoration by the time the
> initializer runs becomes an ancestor of ActionController::Base, and
> reloading MyDecoration is pointless, it won't affect that ancestor
> chain.

But maybe this isn't the right solution, I again failed to make it work with the following

```
  initializer "decorate CcsCms::BasePublicController" do
    ActiveSupport.on_load(:ccs_cms_base_public_controller) do
      include CcsCms::BasePublicDecorator
    end
  end
```

Generating the following error

```
zeitwerk/loader/callbacks.rb:25:in `on_file_autoloaded': expected file /home/jamie/Development/rails/comtech/r7/ccs_cms/engines/public_theme/app/decorators/controllers/ccs_cms/base_public_decorator.rb to define constant Controllers::CcsCms::BasePublicDecorator, but didn't (Zeitwerk::NameError)
```

So back to the solution provided [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#decorating-classes-and-modules-from-engines), thank's again for the answer below I tried the following which did work finally

```
  config.to_prepare do
    overrides = Engine.root.join("app", "decorators")
    Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(overrides)
    p = Engine.root.join("app", "decorators")
    loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.for_gem
    loader.ignore(p)
    Dir.glob(Engine.root.join("app", "decorators", "**", "*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
      Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
    end
  end
```

Comment: turn on eager class loading your development environment -- this will recreate the error -- odds are good there is something not where it is supposed to be to load properly

Comment: Have you read https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#decorating-classes-and-modules-from-engines by chance?

Comment: @dbugger that was very enlightening, thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem here is that when lazy loading, nobody is referencing a constant called `...::BasePublicDecorator`. However, Zeitwerk expects that constant to be defined in that file, and the mismatch is found when eager loading.

The solution is to configure the autoloader to ignore the decorators, because you are handling their loading, and because they do not define constants after their names. [This documentation](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/classic_to_zeitwerk_howto.html#decorating-classes-and-modules-from-engines) has an example. It needs to be adapted to your engine, but you'll see the idea.

For completeness, let me also explain that in Zeitwerk, eager loading is a recursive `const_get`, not a recursive `require`. This is to guarantee that if you access the constant, loading succeeds or fails consistently in both modes (and it is also a tad more efficient). Recursive `const_get` still issues `require` calls via `Module#autoload`, and if you ran one for some file idempotence also applies, but Zeitwerk detects the expected constant is not defined anyway, which is an error condition.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have been learning a lot about this subject but failed totally to switch off autoloading for the decorator path that was described in the link but in the process of trying I stumbled on this https://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#config-autoload-once-paths which has a, nicer I think, approach to the one I was using with an engine initializer including a decorator but I am unable to adapt that to work either, At least I understand the problem now, just can't figure the code needed to solve it. I think I need to update my question

Comment: Take into account that given two files called `foo.rb` at the same hierarchical level, Zeitwerk expects both to define `Foo`, but only the first one found will be loaded. This is in part because `Module#autoload` expects one single file to `require`, and in part to mimick Ruby's `require` behavior (the first found is loaded, any further ones are ignored). I'll check your edit!

Comment: I got it to work, thank you very much, see my last attempt, perhaps you could update your answer with that last bit of code

Comment: The engine should not define an additional loader. Engines code is managed by the parent application. If you like the `on_load` idiom, you can do the same with the main autoloader `Rails.autoloader.main.on_load('CcsCms::BasePublicController') { |klass| include module in klass`. That is pretty neat and works well with reloading.

Comment: Using a different comment to explain that Active Support `on_load` is a totally different hook only used to wait until some Rails components are loaded, because Rails is the one that knows when things are ready to be used. It is unrelated to autoloading.

Comment: Thank you, I have a working solution that I will stick with for the minute, I don't have the luxury to explore the on_load option, I am trying to get a Ukrainian support site up rather urgently for our group. Just one last problem to solve now

Comment: Would you happen to know what my issue might be with this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71727806/rails-7-delayed-job-invoking-rake-task-causes-application-has-already-been-initi, Iam only asking because this is pretty urgent and it's my last stumbling block and I am pretty sure it is related somehow to the question you have answered here