# Rails 7 Delayed Job invoking an engines rake task causes Application has already been initialized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, delayed-job, ruby-on-rails-7

How to correctly invoke a rake task? In an engine I have a rake task and a delayed_job_active_record job. The task will run perfectly in any environment independently of the delayed_job_active_record job, the delayed job actually runs fine in development mode, however I get the following output in production

```
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.502316 #1856]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob] [12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484] Performing CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob (Job ID: 12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484) from Async(default) enqueued at 2022-04-03T16:04:04Z
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.505796 #1856]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob] [12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484] Applying css
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.505837 #1856]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob] [12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484] Calling write_css rake
E, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.506098 #1856] ERROR -- : [ActiveJob] [CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob] [12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484] Error performing CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob (Job ID: 12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484) from Async(default) in 3.79ms: RuntimeError (Application has been already initialized.):
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:371:in `initialize!'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/releases/20220403135814/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/
```

The job:

```
require 'rake'
Rails.application.load_tasks
module CcsCms
  module PublicTheme
    class UpdateAssetsJob < ApplicationJob
      queue_as :default

      def perform(*args)
        Rails.logger.info("Applying css")
        Rails.logger.info("Calling write_css rake")
        Rake::Task[:write_css].invoke #the failing task
        Rails.logger.info("Reenabling write_css rake")
        Rake::Task[:write_css].reenable
        Rails.logger.info("Calling apply_css rake")
        Rake::Task[:apply_css].invoke
        Rails.logger.info("Reenabling apply_css rake")
        Rake::Task[:apply_css].reenable
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The task write_css.rake

```
require 'rake'
#require 'rails'
desc "Applying Theme, will restart server and may take a while!"

task :write_css => :environment do
  Rails.logger.info("Writing css")
  t = CcsCms::PublicTheme::Theme.current_theme
  if !t.blank?
    puts("@@@@ Theme id is #{t.id}")
    c = CcsCms::PublicTheme::Css.new
    c.write_css(t)
  else
    puts("@@@@ No current theme available")
  end
end
```

CcsCms::PublicTheme is an engine and all jobs, tasks and classes are in that engine, the host rails app itself is an empty shell and gets all it's functionality from various engines. This issue could possibly be linked to the engine.rb file?

```
require "deface"
require 'ccs_cms_admin_dashboard'
require 'ccs_cms_custom_page'
require 'ccs_cms_core'
require 'css_menu'
#require 'tinymce-rails'
require 'delayed_job_active_record'
require 'daemons'
require 'sprockets/railtie'
require 'sassc-rails'

module CcsCms
  module PublicTheme
    class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
      isolate_namespace CcsCms::PublicTheme
      paths["app/views"] << "app/views/ccs_cms/public_theme"

      initializer "ccs_cms.assets.precompile" do |app|
        app.config.assets.precompile += %w( public_theme_manifest.js )
      end

      initializer :assets do |config|
        Rails.application.config.assets.paths << root.join("")
      end

      initializer :append_migrations do |app|
        unless app.root.to_s.match?(root.to_s)
          config.paths['db/migrate'].expanded.each do |p|
            app.config.paths['db/migrate'] << p
          end
        end
      end

      initializer :active_job_setup do |app|
        app.config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
      end

      config.to_prepare do
        overrides = Engine.root.join("app", "decorators")
        Rails.autoloaders.main.ignore(overrides)
        p = Engine.root.join("app", "decorators")
        loader = Zeitwerk::Loader.for_gem
        loader.ignore(p)
        Dir.glob(Engine.root.join("app", "decorators", "**", "*_decorator*.rb")) do |c|
          Rails.configuration.cache_classes ? require(c) : load(c)
        end
      end

#Don't think these generators declarations work. Will see with the first scaffold
      config.generators do |g|
        g.test_framework :rspec,
          fixtures: false,
          request: false,
          view_specs: false,
          helper_specs: false,
          controller_specs: false,
          routing_specs: false
        g.fixture_replacement :factory_bot
        g.factory_bot dir: 'spec/factories'
      end

    end
  end
end
```

The full stack trace

```
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.465944 #1856]  INFO -- : [3520be5c-20db-4600-9f87-71b18b2bb875] Started PATCH "/admin_dashboard/themes/1" for 86.143.233.6 at 2022-04-03 16:04:04 +0000
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.467383 #1856]  INFO -- : [3520be5c-20db-4600-9f87-71b18b2bb875] Processing by CcsCms::PublicTheme::ThemesController#update as HTML
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.467624 #1856]  INFO -- : [3520be5c-20db-4600-9f87-71b18b2bb875]   Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"[FILTERED]", "theme"=>{"name"=>"Comtech theme", "current_theme"=>"1", "banner_attributes"=>{"banner_text"=>"Complete Comtech Solutions", "text_position"=>"center", "background_colour"=>"white", "background_image"=>"radial-gradient(#F2F3F5 50%, #D0D5D9)", "font_attributes"=>{"name"=>"Georgia", "id"=>"1"}, "id"=>"1"}}, "commit"=>"Update Theme", "id"=>"1"}
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.501836 #1856]  INFO -- : [3520be5c-20db-4600-9f87-71b18b2bb875] [ActiveJob] Enqueued CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob (Job ID: 12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484) to Async(default)
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.503843 #1856]  INFO -- : [3520be5c-20db-4600-9f87-71b18b2bb875] Redirected to https://cms.completecomtechsolutions.co.uk/admin_dashboard/themes/1
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.504220 #1856]  INFO -- : [3520be5c-20db-4600-9f87-71b18b2bb875] Completed 302 Found in 36ms (ActiveRecord: 4.7ms | Allocations: 2578)
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.502316 #1856]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob] [12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484] Performing CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob (Job ID: 12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484) from Async(default) enqueued at 2022-04-03T16:04:04Z
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.505796 #1856]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob] [12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484] Applying css
I, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.505837 #1856]  INFO -- : [ActiveJob] [CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob] [12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484] Calling write_css rake
E, [2022-04-03T16:04:04.506098 #1856] ERROR -- : [ActiveJob] [CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob] [12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484] Error performing CcsCms::PublicTheme::UpdateAssetsJob (Job ID: 12cb3d46-086f-4f36-9664-71d6eee20484) from Async(default) in 3.79ms: RuntimeError (Application has been already initialized.):
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:371:in `initialize!'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/releases/20220403135814/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.11.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:30:in `require'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/polyglot-0.3.5/lib/polyglot.rb:65:in `require'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.5.4/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:35:in `require'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:348:in `require_environment!'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/railties-7.0.2.3/lib/rails/application.rb:510:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `block in execute'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `each'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:281:in `execute'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:219:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:243:in `block in invoke_prerequisites'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `each'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:241:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:218:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `synchronize'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:199:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/rake-13.0.6/lib/rake/task.rb:188:in `invoke'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/bundler/gems/ccs-cms-public-theme-engine-b455bf39a4e8/app/jobs/ccs_cms/public_theme/update_assets_job.rb:11:in `perform'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:59:in `block in _perform_job'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/i18n-1.10.0/lib/i18n.rb:328:in `with_locale'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/translation.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/zones.rb:66:in `use_zone'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/timezones.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Timezones>'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:58:in `_perform_job'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:20:in `_perform_job'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:46:in `perform_now'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:14:in `block in perform_now'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:25:in `block in instrument'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `block in instrument'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:24:in `instrument'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:206:in `instrument'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:35:in `instrument'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/instrumentation.rb:14:in `perform_now'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:18:in `block in perform_now'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:25:in `tag_logger'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/logging.rb:18:in `perform_now'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:24:in `block in execute'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:54:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `block in wrap'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:92:in `wrap'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:71:in `wrap'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:53:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `instance_exec'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:127:in `block in run_callbacks'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-7.0.2.3/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:138:in `run_callbacks'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/execution.rb:22:in `execute'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/activejob-7.0.2.3/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb:70:in `perform'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `run_task'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:343:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `loop'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `catch'
/home/comtechmaster/apps/ccs_cms_master/shared/bundle/ruby/3.0.0/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.10/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:333:in `block in create_worker'
```

I'm not sure what other info may be needed, is this as simple as not calling the rake task properly from the job?
As mentioned, running the rake task manually from the command line in the production environment works fine

Comment: have you tried running in production mode locally and see if it fails? you could just invert your calls, put your logic into a job and call Job.perform_now from a rake task and Job.perform_later from controllers... you're also not running with delayed_job, but with default async backend indicated by `Async(default)`

Comment: @Alex Yes, it fails locally, I hadn't spotted that I wasn't running with delayed_job, thank you, I am rushing this a bit and obviously I have failed to configure delayed job properly. neat idea about switching the code logic into the job. I'll definitely give that a go, I have a temporary work around by calling the rake tasks using backticks rather than invoking Rake which is working. Thank you for your insight